# Vantiv payment gateway authentication error using python?

Tags: python, integration, payment-gateway

I'm trying to integrate [Vantiv payment gateway](https://www.vantiv.com/payment-technology/gateway-services) using python language.

But when I request on URL [`https://w1.mercurycert.net/PaymentsAPI/Credit/Sale`](https://w1.mercurycert.net/PaymentsAPI/Credit/Sale) with the provided test credentials `merchant id: 755847002` and `password: xyz` it still gives me an error message like:

```
Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
```

I am passing JSON data as provided in the documentation:

```
card_data = {
    "InvoiceNo": "1",
    "RefNo": "1",
    "Memo": "MPS Example JSON v1.0",
    "Purchase": "1.00",
    "Frequency": "OneTime",
    "RecordNo": "RecordNumberRequested",
    "TerminalName": "MPS Terminal",
    "ShiftID": "MPS Shift",
    "OperatorID": "MPS Operator",
    "AcctNo": "4003000123456781",
    "ExpDate": "0517",
    "Address": "4 Corporate Square",
    "Zip": "30329",
    "CVVData": "880",
}
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic [Wzc1NTg0NzAwMV06W3h5el0=]',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
payment = requests.post(
    'https://w1.mercurycert.net/PaymentsAPI/Credit/Sale',
    headers=headers,
    data=card_data)
```

When I look at the response variable `payment`, it still shows that error message.
Can anyone help me on how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, All I needed was to encode "Authorization" header and it worked.

I was using this API at wrong place, API that I used (RESP API) can be used with scanner devices only which can encode data. Instead I needed to use Hosted Checkout API and it worked for me.